# Regex to use params in path

Tags: javascript, regex, react-router

How to create a path that can handle zero, one, the other or both parameters at once (react router v5).

For example:

`/offers /offers/q-shoes /offers/London /offers/London/q-shoes`

I am trying to achieve it this way, unfortunately in this case the path `/offers/London` and `/offers` is not captured

```
import React from 'react';
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Home, Browse } from './Pages';

const re = pathToRegexp('/offers/:location?/q-:search?');

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={re}>
        <Browse />
      </Route>
     
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) you can use string or array of strings as path.

pathToRegexp function returning a RegEx object so you cannot use it. Instead, you should use an array of strings, with the order being more specific to less specific.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

const Component = withRouter((props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{props.title}</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(props.match.params)}</div>
    </div>
  );
});

const Home = () => <Component title="Home" />;
const Browse = () => <Component title="Browse" />;
const NoMatch = () => <Component title="NoMatch" />;

const pathArray = ["/offers/:location?/q-:search?", "/offers/:location?"];

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <Link to="/">/Home</Link>
      <Link to="/offers">/offers</Link>
      <Link to="/offers/q-shoes">/offers/q-shoes</Link>
      <Link to="/offers/London">/offers/London</Link>
      <Link to="/offers/London/q-shoes">/offers/London/q-shoes</Link>
    </div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={pathArray}>
        <Browse />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route>
        <NoMatch />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default App;
```